# Unable to get the attributes of an object from object array saved in Mongodb document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating a cart for an ecommerce website, and decided to store cart items for users in Mongodb. I can store the items with no problem and the show up in Mongodb, but when I try to get the attributes from individual items, it says the object is not defined.

this is the schema for the cart

```
const cartSchema = new Schema(
  {
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    cartItems: [
      {
        itemName: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        quantity: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
        },
        itemPicture: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
```

but when I get a users cart and log to console it looks like this

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("123_documentID_123"),
    email: 'users_email',
    cartItems: [ [Object] ],
    createdAt: 2023-11-19T08:36:38.817Z,
    updatedAt: 2023-11-19T08:36:38.817Z,
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

when I try to access the cartItems array, it tells me the object is undefined but when  I check the mongodb console, the array has the cartItem I am trying to access

```
 console.log(item.cartItems[0])
```

always returns this error

```
console.log(item.cartItems[0])
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

this is the same way I am accessing the items of an array in another schema I have and it works fine, the only difference is its an array of strings not objects. Any Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `item` is an array so I assume you used `Model.find()` to locate your `Cart`?

When you execute `Model.find()` mongoose expects 0 or more results so will always return an array (empty or otherwise).

To log `cartItems[0]` you would need to do:

```js
console.log(item[0].cartItems[0]);
```

If you know you are only looking for one single cart then use `Cart.findById(id)` if you have the `Cart._id` value or use `Cart.findOne({email: req.body.email})` if you are querying on another field. Both of these methods will return a single document as opposed to an array.

Comment: Ahh thank you, I don't know how I missed that!

Comment: @Abe you're welcome.